# How does 'go get' work when given a not known code hosting domain site?

Tags: go

Let's take an example. The command below will do:

`go get robpike.io/ivy`

This will get me the content of the repository under $GOPATH/src. Great!

Now, how does it work?

First, robpike.io/ivy replies with a HTTP-redirect:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

`<a href="http://godoc.org/robpike.io/ivy">Found</a>`

From reading at `go help importpath`, I learn that:

> If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a
>   version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import
>   over https/http and looks for a  tag in the document's HTML

However, looking for a metatag inside the content of the redirected page using:

`curl -D --raw https://godoc.org/robpike.io/ivy | grep go-import`

returns nothing.

Reading further:

> The repo-root is the root of the version control system containing a
>   scheme and not containing a .vcs qualifier.
>
> For example,
>
> import "example.org/pkg/foo"
>
> will result in the following requests:
>
> https://example.org/pkg/foo?go-get=1 (preferred)
>
> http://example.org/pkg/foo?go-get=1  (fallback, only with -insecure)

Again:

`curl -D --raw https://robpike.io/ivy?go-get=1`

returns nothing.

So the question is: how can I do the same thing as Mr. Rob Pike and use my own site with the `go get` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last command you entered does return data. When I run `curl -D --raw https://robpike.io/ivy\?go-get\=1` in my terminal, I get the following data back:

```html
<meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/toy git https://github.com/robpike/toy.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/translate git https://github.com/robpike/translate.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/freq git https://github.com/robpike/freq.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/hira git https://github.com/robpike/hira.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/kana git https://github.com/robpike/kana.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/kata git https://github.com/robpike/kata.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/nihongo git https://github.com/robpike/nihongo.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/typo git https://github.com/robpike/typo.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/filter git https://github.com/robpike/filter.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/unicode git https://github.com/robpike/unicode.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/doc git https://github.com/robpike/doc.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/scrub git https://github.com/robpike/scrub.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/strings git https://github.com/robpike/strings.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/ivy git https://github.com/robpike/ivy.git"><meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/cmd/now git https://github.com/robpike/now.git">
```

Ths allows the go get command to resolve the vanity path to git repositories.

Comment: I got bitten by the escape character bug : `curl -D --raw https://robpike.io/ivy\?go-get\=1`. Thank you for timely reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: Ah yes. My zsh config automatically escapes input when I paste it in.

Comment: I use zsh. Would you mind sharing the line that does that?

Comment: I'm using [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) not sure exactly which line fixes that.

Answer (score 2):

The command `curl -D --raw 'https://robpike.io/ivy?go-get=1'` returns an HTML document containing the tag

```
<meta name="go-import" content="robpike.io/ivy git https://github.com/robpike/ivy.git">
```

The `go get` command uses this meta tag to resolve the vanity import path to an actual git repository. You can do the same.

Comment: A vanity package path? I like that term. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Go team uses the term "vanity path" when referring to the feature.